# Will two objects/arrays in javascript == each other by coincidence?

Tags: javascript, reference

Lets say I have array a.

```
var a = [1,2,3];
```

And then there is array b.

```
var b = [1,2,3];
```

Is there ANY possible chance that `a == b` will return true? Even if it is one in a million. (I know that normally `a == b` will be false, but I am wondering if there is a chance that it will be true.)

Comment: No, because if the objects are referencable, they haven't been garbage collected - the objects in memory they reference must be separate.

Comment: *wondering if there is a chance that it will be true* - absolutely zero "chance" - programming languages are not a lottery, they have a defined behaviour, and by definition of the javascript language, in the proposed scenario, `a` does not equal `b`

Comment: @JaromandaX _"programming languages are not a lottery"_ Well, that's not entirely true. There are plenty of examples of pieces of code that may or may not yield a 'true' result depending on configuration, or input, or sheer luck. One of them is string literals in C: will `"abc"` pointer-compare equal to `"abc"` found elsewhere in the program? The answer is that it depends. (In that case it does ultimately depend on deterministic factors, but hopefully I have persuaded you that it's often a little more than just reading the standard-defined semantics.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant part of the spec is [11.9.3 The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3):

> The comparison `x == y`, where `x` and `y` are values, produces `true` or `false`. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> 1. **If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then**
>
>    1. If Type(x) is Undefined, return true.
>    2. If Type(x) is Null, return true.
>    3. If Type(x) is Number, then
>
>       1. If x is NaN, return false.
>       2. If y is NaN, return false.
>       3. If x is the same Number value as y, return true.
>       4. If x is +0 and y is −0, return true.
>       5. If x is −0 and y is +0, return true.
>       6. Return false.
>    4. If Type(x) is String, then return true if x and y are exactly the same sequence of characters (same length and same characters in corresponding positions). Otherwise, return false.
>    5. If Type(x) is Boolean, return true if x and y are both true or both false. Otherwise, return false.
>    6. **Return true if x and y refer to the same object. Otherwise, return false.**

(Emphasis mine.)

So the answer to your question is no. `a == b` only returns `true` if they are in fact the same object.